# Nuget packages seems installed after Git checkout of VS2015 solution

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs, nuget

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution composed of a:

- web site
- library (DLL)
- console application

The solution is versioned with Git. I'm currently using the .gitignore file you can find at:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

The problem is that if you clone the repository and checkout the project, everything *seems* fine: it seems that every projects has its own correct Nuget pakages. Those packages as listed as "installed".
When I build, it fails because the actual files are missing.
For example, if the Nuget package is a library, VS2015 does not try to restore the necessary files in bin/

The only step I can do to "fix" it is to perform a complete reinstallation of the packages, using the command:
`update-package -reinstall`
from within the package manager console.

I can't get what I am missing here.
In my repository the /packages folder is missing (should be correct, the `restore` method of nuget should take care of download them again.
For each project, the `packages.config` file is there.

I think is something related to Git and (un)tracked files. When it comes to TFS, I usually don't have any trouble restoring Nuget packages (they are even automatically restored during build). In my Git project, there aren't packages to restore.

Googling for that does not help.
Maybe someone has some hint?
Thanks.

Comment: In the past, when I inherited a large project with numerous nuget restore issues, I [found a script](https://github.com/owen2/AutomaticPackageRestoreMigrationScript) that helped clean things up and I never looked back.  Now VS2015 builds, command-line builds and "git pulls" on a clean directory can be reliably built without any issues.  Might want to visit the script page and see if it would help you.

Comment: Please check the missing files path in project References from Properties window, make sure the references assemblies paths are the same on your check-in machine and check-out machine. And also please check whether there has different repositoryPath value set in NuGet.config on these two machines.

Comment: Does the nuget package folder exist after checking out the project?